# Conditional compiling of Objective-C in a Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, swift

I have an Objective-C category that I've been using for a while for both iOS and OSX projects and I want to use it in a Swift project as-is...until I have the time to translate it to Swift.

Here's the top of my category's .h file:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

I've included it in the bridging header, but when I build the project for iOS, I get an error saying that it can't find the file Cocoa/Cocoa.h.

Why is it even looking for it? Doesn't the conditional compile still work even in a Swift project? It's still compiling an Objective-C file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `#import "TargetConditionals.h"` in your source file.

```
#import "TargetConditionals.h"
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

Or add "-DTARGET_OS_IPHONE" to the "Other C Flags" section of the target build options.